# .htaccess, Laravel & Ikonboard

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel

I have to admit, creating mod-rewrite rules still confuses me! So, I'm after some help please...

I've taken on a site built in Laravel, but now need to add an existing forum into the domain. The forum is Ikonboard, which on the live site lives in the cgi_bin folder. When I copy this to the new site, I can't get access because the htaccess is rewriting ALL URL's to the public folder (where Laravel want's it).

So, how can I make any requests to the cgi_bin folder work as well as keeping the rewrite to public for Laravel?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Rewrite to 'public' folder
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
RewriteCond {%REQUEST_URI} !^/cgi_bin
```

Add this above your other `REQUEST_URI` rule. If `cgi_bin` is in the URI, then it will stop rewriting.

**Edit** - Based on your response with regards to the directory structure, it seems to be wrong. Your `www` directory **is** your `public` directory. So, your structure should look like this:

- `/www/` (your public folder)

  - `bundles/` (etc...)
  - `cgi_bin/`
  - `.htaccess`
  - `index.php`
- `/laravel/`
- (etc...)

Change your directory structure to look like that, and make sure that your `.htaccess` file has the following in it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If you call a CGI document, it should pass through because `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` is set above. All assets should pass through as well. You do not need to specify whether or not the `cgi_bin` folder is being requested. If it does not work, then add the line as I had originally in this answer (except, you would put the rule just under `RewriteEngine On`.

Comment: Where is your `index.php` file, and your `.htaccess` file? Both should be in the `public` directory. Your `cgi_bin` directory should also be in there. Everything else (except for resources, such as images) should be below the web root. If you are not sure, please post your directory structure in your question.

Comment: Hey Mike - thanks for your help! The root is 'www'. This folder contains the .htaccess file, the public folder (for Laravel) and the cgi_bin folder.

Comment: No, that structure is incorrect. Laravel does not want a `public` folder under the public root. Your public root **is** your `www` folder.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29971/discussion-between-jezb-and-mike-anthony)